# what parameters stepAIC accepts?

Tags: r, kernlab

I am using stepAIC() function from library (MASS).

And per the documentation it says that I can pass an 'object':

> a model of an appropriate class. This is used as the initial model in
>   the stepwise search.

What is an appropriate class?

I created a model using ksvm() but, stepAIC seems not to accept it.

I am using the code:

```
stepAIC(svmFit, direction="both")
```

And I get the error

```
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

The object **svmFit** I am passing is of class:

```
[1] "ksvm"
attr(,"package")
[1] "kernlab"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what models are accepted, but we can take some guesses based on the source.

It needs a model that can be accessed using `$` (i.e. typically an S3 class). Your model is an S4 class, and therefore by definition will not work.

In addition, there need to be at least a working method for the model class for the the following functions: `formula`, `terms`, `update.formula`, `nobs`, `extractAIC`, `deviance`, `update` (judging from a scan of the source). This can be a default method, such as `stats:::formula.default`, which finds either `x$formula`, `$terms`, `$call$formula` or a formula attribute.

If one or more of these methods have not been implemented, then it will also fail.

Basically, it is making a lot of assumptions that work for many of the modelling functions, such as `lm` and `glm`. One can write a new modelling function that will create models that are compatible with `stepAIC`, and a comprehensive list may be difficult to create!